# Global back button

Tags: lua

I'm working on a game in which I have a bunch of overlays and one scene which is called `game.lua`. I wanted to make it, when I press back button (hardware button on Android device), game would, if there's an overlay, close the overlay and if there's no overlay (just `game.lua` scene), it would show `exitmenu.lua`(simple pop-up menu).

```
function onKeyEvent( event )
        if(event.keyName == "back") then
            local CurrentScene = composer.getSceneName("current")
            local CurrentOverlay = composer.getSceneName("overlay")

            if CurrentScene == "Scenes.game" and CurrentOverlay == nil then
                composer.showOverlay("Scenes.exitmenu", {isModal = true})
                return true                    
            elseif CurrentOverlay ~= nil and CurrentOverlay ~= "Scenes.exitmenu" then
                composer.hideOverlay("fade", 500)
                return true
            end
        end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("key", onKeyEvent)
```

What happens is, when I press back button while overlay is on, function hides the overlay and also shows `exitmenu.lua` overlay. I have no idea what is wrong with my code, any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Here on SO you can answer (and accept) your own question instead of making an edit. That way your question is removed from the "unanswered" list :)

Comment: Oh, didn't think about that! Thank you sir. Will do!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I've fixed it! I needed to add and `event.phase == "down"`, which makes my button press do function only once. That was the fix.